# Accessing a nested object in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

What would the Blade syntax be for retrieving the following from a query response? The data is eager loaded. Each image is linked to a separate table. How do you access an object within an object in Blade? Pretty new to Laravel. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Once you pas them as data in your controller, inside your blade templates you should echo them as a objects:

```
{{ $images[0]->id }}
{{ $images[0]->host_image->path }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

In your action you need to pass the data to the blade view:

```
return view('someview', compact('images'));//name of variable $images
```

**View**

Just use the variable:

```
@foreach($image as $image)
    {{-- Do Something --}}
@endForEach
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command:

```
{{ $images->first()->id }}
{{ $images->first()->host_image->first()>path }}
```